# Deployment error in xamarin project "InstallPackageAssemblies" -- FAILED

Tags: xamarin

In Xamarin project I got deployment errors those are below

> "InstallPackageAssemblies" -- FAILED.
>
> "_Upload" in project "LiUpHandy.csproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Done building project "LiUpHandy.csproj" -- FAILED.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I found the solution to this problem
Follow these steps :

```
    > Go to settings on your device
    > Application Manager
    > Find 'All' or 'Running' Tab's apps
    > Find your own app's package name like com.packagename
    > Uninstall that package name i.e. app
    > Hit the Debug in your VS2015 to run Xamarin.Android App on your real device
```

Answer (score -1):

Had same thing.
Try running vs as Admin.

I had some more issues after.
try new sdk, ndk, jdk.
The one from unreal engine nvidia pack worked for me. Make sure you change path in tools->options->Xamarin